# Select Query taking long time in first call and from second it is normal

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing a mobile application. It has a table with 4000 files. These files are inserted at the time of installation of the application. After completion of insertion, when i call the select query for the first time, it was taking 160 seconds to give results. And from the second call it was taking only 2 seconds. Is their a way to reduce the time of first call

Comment: It's called caching and you may observe it in databases as well. This is why your successive calls are faster. You would need to show your table structure, query.

Comment: I have a table with 24 columns. After insertion i was calling select statement(select * from tableName). This query takes long time in the first call and from second it was fine. As you said caching is correct. Is their any way to increase performance

Comment: As I said earlier, you need to give us details. Caching is the reason you're seeing the times of execution like they are.